# Prove a certain cubic function is uniformly continuous on the unit interval

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

> Let $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = -x^3+2x$. Prove using the definition of uniform continuity that the function is uniformly continuous.

By definition $\forall \varepsilon >0$ $\exists \delta>0$ such that, $|f(x)-f(y)|< \varepsilon$ whenever $x,y, \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|x-y|< \delta$.

Using this I get $|-x^3+2x+y^3-2y| = |-x^3+y^3 +2x-2y|$. How should I continue from here? I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Try dividing (synthetically) the expression $y^3-x^3 +2(x-y)$ by $x-y$. Then see if you can bound the result.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe you could use the mean value theorem.

Comment: Note that $|f'(x)| \le 5$.

Comment: copper.hat . Why not make your last comment a one line answer (Lipschitz)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle inequality yields
$$
|y^3-x^32+2x-2y|\leq |y^3-x^3|+2|x-y|<|y-x||y^2+yx+x^2|+2\delta<3\delta+2\delta=5\delta. 
$$
So given any $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=\epsilon/5$

Comment: Where did the $2$ come from for the first inequality?

Comment: $|2x-2y|=2|x-y|$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$|-x^3+y^3+2x-2y|=|x-y||2+y^2+x^2+yx|\leq 5|x-y|.$$
Take $\delta =\frac{\varepsilon }{5},$ and thus $$|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon .$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how did you get from $|x-y||2+y^2+x^2+yx|$ to $5|x-y|$?

Comment: Because $|x|,|y|\leq 1$. @Daniel

Comment: How did you find that out? @Surb

Comment: @Daniel: Do you understand what $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ means ?

Comment: Ah, my bad.....

Answer (score 0):

The depart is
$$
|-x^3+ 2x + y^3 -2y|= |-(x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2) + 2(x-y)|= |x-y||2-x^2-xy-y^2|
$$
now let's take a value $\epsilon$. If 
$$
|x-y||2-x^2-xy-y^2|<\epsilon
$$
holds, then
$$
|x-y|<\frac{\epsilon}{|2-x^2-xy-y^2|}
$$
holds as well.

The minimal $\delta$ (such that the above inequality holds for all ) is found when the denominator for $x,y\in [0,1]$ is minimum, hence when $x,y=0$. Then we find
$$
\delta=\epsilon/2.$$

Comparing with the other answers this seams to be the higher bound value for $\delta$ found so far.